# Mongodb UpdateOne on node js

Tags: mongodb, collections, callback, mongodb-query

I am facing an issue with MongoDB updateOne. Please check this piece and let me know what is wrong.

```js
logger.debug("newindex : " + newindex);
```

//This line is Printing 1596

```js
logger.debug("pHash : " + pHash);
```

//This line is printing `920e5ef13b1e097a104eb62e9e9c33d069553d807e0bc30a18a3a70fac10db20`

but the below code is not updating the database.

```js
dbobject.collection("Products")
    .updateOne({ index: newindex }, { $set: { previoushash: pHash } })
    .then(function (res) {
        callback();
        db.close();
    });
```

I have tried without callback, with callback, with update, with updateOne, with quotes etc....no result.
pls check..

NOTE : "Products" collection is existing. 1596 record is existing. DB is up and running.

Comment: Could you paste the document you're trying to modify and print `res` variable from callback ?

Comment: DBRecord:

{"_id":"5e0312ad6b92b506a073d862",
"index":"1596",
"timestamp":"2019-12-24T12:52:35",
"data":{"name":"prod1"},
"previoushash":"test",
"hash":"a76d908f7621b2536e56d80a242b1e27ae3d5e23980bd95d0588a86e71d7a393"}

logger.debug("newindex : " + newindex); //Printing 1596
logger.debug("pHash : " + pHash); //printing 920e5ef13b1e097a104eb62e9e9c33d069553d807e0bc30a18a3a70fac10db20
dbobject.collection("Products").updateOne({index : newindex}, {$set: { previoushash : pHash }}).then(function (res) { 
 logger.debug("result : " + res); //not printing
 callback(); 
 db.close();
});

Comment: Is the datatype of `newindex` a string or a number?